# VBA Code not working since upgrading excel from 32bit to 64bit. Active X component can't create object

Tags: excel, vba, 32bit-64bit

I recently upgraded my PC from windows 7 to windows 10. I have maintained using office 2016 throughout the process, however I am now using excel 64bit whereas previously my VBA code was written in 32bit. I am simply trying to automate an email using excel VBA:

```
Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim outlookmailitem As Object

Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.createitem(0)
```

The code falls over at the line:

```
Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Where I receive an error:
Run-time error '429': Active X can't create object.

I have done some pretty extensive research and cannot find a solution to the error. I am led to believe that I need to alter my code slightly to be compatible with 64bit VBA but I am unaware of how to do so.

I have tried:

- Using the early binding method (e.g. Dim outlookapp as Outlook.Application)
- Ticking certain references in the Tools>References section
- Checking the correct file path is located in the Registry section

None of which have worked. I would ideally like to avoid uninstalling 64bit and reinstalling 32bit. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you get the error in line where you create the Outlook object? Which references did you select?

Comment: I put the error trapping mode on to break in class module and it highlighted the line I mentioned. I wasn't entirely sure what references to select. The thread I read told me to investigate "Missing" references but I wasn't entirely sure what this meant. Can you shed any light on what references I should tick? or how I should find out what references to tick?

Comment: Go to the VBE>Tools>Refrences... if anything is missing, it will be immediately visible in the listbox and marked as "MISSING:xxx" where xxx is the missing refrence. I'd suggest taking out the Microsoft Outlook refrence and trying it like that. Since you are using late binding, this might actually get in the way...

Comment: There are no references labelled "Missing" in my list. I ticked "Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library" ran the code and got the same error. I then unticked it, ran the code and still got the same error. I have just looked at the file path in my C drive that references outlook and it is and OLB file as opposed to an application. Could this have something to do with it? if so- how do I change?